# Dúvida sobre criação de metodos "repetidos" no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Pessoa, comecei a utilizar o rails a pouco tempo e estou com uma dúvida de como melhorar o código abaixo:

Tenho um model chamado User que tem um atributo chamado Role para permissões. 
Porém, para ficar mais legível acabei criando os seguintes métodos:

```
def is_superadmin?
    if self.role.description == "super_admin"
        return true
    end 
  end

  def is_admin?
    if self.role.description == "admin"
        return true
    end 
  end

  def is_analyst?
    if self.role.description == "analyst"
        return true
    end 
  end

  def is_client?
    if self.role.description == "client"
        return true
    end 
  end
```

Teria como melhorar isso, pois se não toda vez que eu adicionar uma nova regra, preciso lembrar de ir no model e criar outro método desses.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode definir os métodos dinamicamente usando [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method):

```
class User

  Role.all.each do |role|
    define_method("is_#{role.description}?") do
      self.role.id == role.id
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!